# quartz can't release file handle

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler

this is my code :

```
public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String logPath = "D:\\mywork\\OMS\\Tymon\\testlog\\testlog.log";
  File file = new File(logPath);

  SchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();
  Scheduler sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
  sched.start();
  JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("a", "b", TestJob.class);

  CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger("c", "d");
  trigger.setCronExpression("0/23 * * * * ?");
  sched.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
 }
}
```

when the job is running, the file **"D:\mywork\OMS\Tymon\testlog\testlog.log"** can't be renamed and deleted.

it seems like the file handle always be held

how fix it ?
please help ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you create  File file = new File(logPath) object.

Seems you never used in else where in your logic.

Comment: may be just add references of "file" object? I think you may have open 1 or 2 input / output streams to this file.

Comment: i just only new a File object never use stream in this program. the job is only sysout some string.

Comment: you are right~~  there is another program holding the file hanlder. quartz write the file by log4j.log4j lock the file. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you opened the file:

File file = new File(logPath);

but where did you close it?

Comment: I suppose scheduleJob will keep running, so the file alway hold the file handler, unless the program run to the end, or you can not do nothing with the file handler.

Comment: i write another program by Thread object. it can work.i don't know why quartz always hold the file handler, confusing......